# Can't Get echo $pdo->lastInsertId(); to output anything

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on a script and need to echo the last inserted ID to a DB but I'm not getting any output.

Note: When running the code below it does insert the data into the DB but after doing so I am not getting the ID of the last inserted row and if anyone could show me what may be askew I'd be most appreciative and I thank you in advance.

Here's the code with specific details obscured for obvious reasons;

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
require_once('connect_file.php');
$Data = $_REQUEST['json'];

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxxxx;dbname=xxxxxx", xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));

$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`,`Facebook_id`,`First_name`) VALUES ('', :xxxxx, :xxxxxxx)";

$sth = $pdo->prepare($query);

try {
$sth->execute(array(
    ":xxxxx" => $Data['id'],
    ":xxxxxxx" => $Data['first_name']
);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

echo $pdo->lastInsertId();

?>
```

Comment: Try adding `$pdo->commit()` after `$sth->execute()`

Comment: What do you get when you echo out the lastInsertId? Just nothing? Could you try doing a var_dump() on $pdo->lastInsertId()?

Comment: @IanBrindley Could you provide an example of where to add $pdo->commit()??

Comment: Immediately after `$sth->execute(array...)`

Comment: @user1578653 That is correct, I get no output "nothing". I don't know about var_dump but I'm open to learn about it. What is it?

Comment: @IanBrindley such as: $sth->execute(array(
    ":xxxxx" => $Data['id'],
    ":xxxxxxx" => $Data['first_name']
);

$pdo->commit();

Comment: var_dump is just another way of printing a variable - it's easier to read. You are echoing out $pdo->lastInsertId() at the moment and get nothing. This could potentially be an empty string, null or a boolean false - you can't tell. Doing var_dump($pdo->lastInsertId()) instead will show you more information such as data type etc. which could help...

Answer (score 0):

You should read the return value of **execute()**, wich is a **boolean**.

I guess it's false and that would mean an error in your request.

Looks to me like you are using id auto-increment in the table *users*.

If that's the case, I would suggest to get your query rid of the *id* columnn

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`Facebook_id`,`First_name`) VALUES (:xxxxx, :xxxxxxx)";
[...]
$sth->execute(array(
    ":xxxxx" => $Data['id'],
    ":xxxxxxx" => $Data['first_name'],
);
```

Then the **lastInsertId()** call should return the id you expect.

Comment: I appreciate the tip regarding the Auto Inc ID, I fixed that but if I put single quotes around the variables it breaks the script and I still get no lastInsertId returned. Ideas?

Comment: @Herode I am assuming you have never had an experience with PDO or prepared statements?

Comment: Allow me to add before making these edits: Will this make a difference? Afterall the code IS inserting the data into the DB.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks @YourCommonSense Now I just hope you'll share what's REALLY wrong in this

Comment: @StuartKaufman My use of 'obviously' was not ill-intented. Maybe it's not the good word, I'm not a native english speaker, sorry if you feeld it offensive. Anyway, back to home I've tested your code here. Quote don't mind after all, my bad. And your code works on my computer... No more ideas right now, sorry... (post edited, also)

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your bootstrap code at the top

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

and this code at the bottom

```
var_dump($pdo->lastInsertId());

$sth = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM users order by id DESC LIMIT 1");
var_dump($sth->fetch());
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll be trying this soon and I'll let you know how it goes but I have to ask: Do I just put this: ini_set('display_errors',1); right below error_reporting(E_ALL);?? And... Why the reference to "bootstrap code"?? I don't know what bootstrap is.

Comment: Nevermind, nothing important. I meant just "the common code you're usually write or include at the top"

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, I'd like to email you a file I'm working with and ask if you could take a look at the code. I now put everything inside a PDO Transaction but it's still having trouble but I'd like to send you this file if you wouldn't mind.

Comment: You can email it but better get rid of useless transaction and run the code I posted

Answer (score 0):

In your query you assign a zero length string `''` to your `ID`.

`$query = "INSERT INTO`users`(`ID`,`Facebook_id`,`First_name`) VALUES ('', :xxxxx, :xxxxxxx)"`;

As I assume you will be using an AUTO_INCREMENT INT column you either  assign a NULL or 0 to have the correct number of parameters.

From [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

> No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column , so MySQL
>   assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly
>   assign NULL or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers.

`$query = "INSERT INTO`users`(`ID`,`Facebook_id`,`First_name`) VALUES (NULL, :xxxxx, :xxxxxxx)"`;

Comment: Hi @David Strachan, Thanks for Chiming In!! I have since changed this part of the script. It's Good to hear from you and I hope all is well.